# Getting errors in the CSS linter when using media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, csslint

When I put the code below through the [CSS Linter](http://csslint.net/) I get six errors. Are these bugs in the linter or the CSS? I can't see anything wrong with the CSS. I can't seem to turn off or ignore the errors either regardless of the settings.

```
@media ( max-width: 320px ) {
    .test {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only had to remove the spaces for it to pass:

```
@media (max-width:320px) {
    .test {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: good to know I suppose it's a bit of an improvement ... still it's pretty picky isn't it ... I think it looks more readable with the spaces, no?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is valid it's just that css link is being picky about the formatting.

If you change it to the following it's quite happy with it:

```
@media(max-width:320px){.test{padding:20px;}}
```

I'd recommend using this site to validate your css:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I know the linter is a bit picky but it is handy to have it run in real time in sublime and all the other stuff I can control in user prefs. This part is a bit shocking though IMO. Thanks for your answer, really helps.